# Testing custom standard compliant containers

Tags: c++, unit-testing, standard-library

I am making custom versions of the standard containers (many reasons, the main one being educational). The containers have the same interface as the standard containers. Now I want to test the containers properly. Is there perchance tests written for the standard library that can potentially be used on any standard compliant container to make sure the containers are working as they should?

I am currently writing my own tests and going with some examples found on [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) but they are definitely not exhaustive.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, take a look in [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) and [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/). You should find something there.

Comment: That is a little more convoluted that I would like. It would be great if all I have to do is link my library against a 'testing' program where I do something like this `typedef MyVector<int> vector<int>` and the tests run. If I cannot find it, this may be a good open-source project for me.